# Trying to retrive Domain name from DNS packet but gettin garbage value

Tags: c, networking, dns, driver

I neet to retrive the Domain name from DNS packet in a driver but Failing to retrive it. Where am I going wrong or how can I retrive it.
I have tried below code to print the domain name.

```
VOID FilterCallback(const FWPS_INCOMING_VALUES0* Values, const FWPS_INCOMING_METADATA_VALUES0* MetaData, PVOID layerdata, const void* context, const FWPS_FILTER* filter, UINT64 flowcontext, FWPS_CLASSIFY_OUT* classifyout)
{
    if (!(classifyout->rights & FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE)) {
        goto end;
    }

    NET_BUFFER_LIST* nbl = (NET_BUFFER_LIST*)layerdata;
    NET_BUFFER* nb = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB(nbl);

    if (nb->CurrentMdl != NULL) {
        UCHAR* data = (UCHAR*)MmGetMdlVirtualAddress(nb->CurrentMdl);

        if (data != NULL) {
            DNS_HEADER* dns_hdr = (DNS_HEADER*)data;

            UCHAR* questionS = data + sizeof(DNS_HEADER);
            KdPrint(("size of header:%d\n", sizeof(DNS_HEADER)));
            KdPrint(("data: "));
            while (*questionS != 0) {
                if ((*questionS & 0xC0) == 0xC0) {
                    USHORT offset = RtlUshortByteSwap(*((USHORT*)questionS)) & 0x3FFF;
                    questionS = data + offset;
                }

                USHORT labelLength = *questionS++;
                for (int i = 0; i < labelLength; i++) {
                    KdPrint(("%c", (char)*questionS++));
                }
                KdPrint(("."));
            }
            KdPrint(("\n"));
        }
    }
> I am getting this data when I run it.
```

data: @žey øÿÿP­Œ™ÿÿP­Œ™ÿÿ¢X¸ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÀ­Œ™ÿÿPdy™ÿÿ0.

data: Ù‹Û33'1òR†Ý `ºˆ0RT5'1òEC)›€ ÊXƒ[Ø.5*y \ßÛßy å`Äe6«¬Å¸OG™ÿÿ” Dá3â$y
˜QI™ÿÿ `    H™ÿÿÀ9åt
øÿÿ
ˆôÿÿÀ9åt
øÿÿ¬Ø¥Òˆ…ÿÿ.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have you read about the format of a dns packet? As it is, the code you posted is hard to read and hard to understand. If you could tell us more that would be helpful.

Comment: If you could upload the code for the struct DNS_HEADER that might also help. Or it might be from windns, in which case that would also help to know. Any other libraries you are using?

Comment: I get the packet data into the NET_BUFFER_LIST structure then get pointer to MDL which contains packet data. And create pointer to the DNS_HEADER structure which cast the starting address of data. And then move pointer to question section.

Comment: The DNS_Header is from windns.h